# SELECT DISTINCT or array_unique not working with my data

Tags: php, mysql, select

Using PHP, I'm generating the following SQL statement (the ID being dynamic depending on the drop-down that is selected:

```
$makeid = intval($_POST['make_id']);

//SELECT partshop_id FROM partshop2categories WHERE category_id = $makeid
$pcats = $objDb->select("partshop2categories", "partshop_id", " category_id=" . $makeid);

foreach ($pcats as $p) {
    // SELECT Brand FROM partshop WHERE id = $p['partshop_id']
    $prods = $objDb->select("partshop", "Brand", " id=" . $p['partshop_id']);
    foreach ($prods as $b) {

        // SELECT DISTINCT id, text FROM Brand_type WHERE ID = $b['Brand']
        $brands = $objDb->selectDistinct("Brand_type", "id, text", "id=" . $b['Brand']." GROUP BY text");

        $brands = array_unique($brands);

        foreach ($brands as $brand) {

            $htmlResponse .= '<option value="' . $brand['id'] . '">' . $brand['text'] . '</option>';
        }

        echo($htmlResponse);
    }
}
```

This code is then producing the following values into my select:

```
<option value="146">AGV</option>
<option value="134">DAYTONA</option>
<option value="134">DAYTONA</option>
```

Surely the SELECT DISTINCT should be removing these duplicates? Here's the arrays that it gives me at the var_dump:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "146" ["text"]=> string(3) "AGV" } }

array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "134" ["text"]=> string(7) "DAYTONA" } }

array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "134" ["text"]=> string(7) "DAYTONA" } }
```

Comment: You have a condition `WHERE id = 146` and you still get id as 134 thats weird.

Comment: If you have a "WHERE id = 146" in your query, then why do you have results with an ID of 134?

Comment: I've altered the code so you can see exactly how I'm getting these values. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What is the query being generated by `$objDb->selectDistinct("Brand_type", "id, text", "id=" . $b['Brand']." GROUP BY text");` ?

Comment: This would run `SELECT id, text FROM Brand_type WHERE ID = # GROUP BY text;` - the ID being dependent on whatever dropdown was selected.

Comment: Looks like you have a white space for text in one of `DAYTONA`

Comment: But the `var_dump` shows the ['text'] of both have a string-length of 7 and I can't see any visible spaces. The actual real response is `<option value="146">AGV</option><option value="146">AGV</option><option value="134">DAYTONA</option><option value="146">AGV</option><option value="134">DAYTONA</option><option value="134">DAYTONA</option>` - I just used two of the duplicates as an example.

Comment: $prods = $objDb->select("partshop", "Brand", " id=" . $p['partshop_id']); or $pcats = $objDb->select("partshop2categories", "partshop_id", " category_id=" . $makeid); In one of these queries it goes wrong. Not the query itself, but the data in the database. I guess that that product is assigned twice to the partshop

Answer (score 0):

With some help from a work colleague it's now working! Here's the amended code:

```
$makeid = intval($_POST['make_id']);

$pcats = $objDb->select("partshop2categories", "partshop_id", " category_id=" . $makeid);
$arrBrands = array();
$htmlResponse = '';
foreach ($pcats as $p) {
    $prods = $objDb->selectDistinct("partshop", "Brand", " id=" . $p['partshop_id'] . " GROUP BY id");
    foreach ($prods as $b) {

        $brands = $objDb->selectDistinct("Brand_type", "id, text", "id=" . $b['Brand']." GROUP BY id");

        foreach ($brands as $brand) {
        if(!in_array($brand['text'], $arrBrands))
        {
            $arrBrands[$brand['id']] = $brand['text'];
        }

        }

    }
}

foreach($arrBrands as $key=>$brand)  {
  $htmlResponse .= '<option value="' . $key . '">' . $brand . '</option>';
}

echo($htmlResponse);
```

A new array for the brands was created. Thanks for the help everyone!